# Optmizing r to java call in rserve

Tags: java, r, optimization, rserve

I am facing a problem while performing optimization using lpSolveAPI in R and Java on a large dataset.

I tried Rserve,RCaller,JRI,Renjin and found that Rserve is what actually suits my need. RCaller has a functionality that has allows to run all the r commands as a batch, but after that the context is lost.In Renjin the lpSolveAPI support is still under development.I also tried Rglpk package in R but the tuning options provided are limited compared to Rglpk.

The loop which is taking a lot of time is as shared below, the eval and assign statements are taking up a majority of run time.

The number of times the loop1 repeats is 300 - more than 3000, similarly loop2 & loop3(depends on input ).

The assign and eval statements cannot be avoided as it is part of the  logic.

Is there something to boost the performance of this loop, or  another library to be used so that the code can be evaluated after the loop is completed(kind of a batch run). Just to get an idea of things – the program with an input of 1000 records completes in 3hrs, and an input of 2000 records is taking more than a day and is getting stuck not sure if it will complete.

```
for( : loop1){
    for ( : loop2) {
        rconn.assign("constraint");
        if ( condition ){
            rconn.voidEval("constraint");
        }else{
            rconn.assign("constraint");
        }
        if( condition ){
            rconn.voidEval("constraint");
        }else{
            rconn.voidEval("constraint");
        }
    }
    for( : loop3) {
        rconn.assign("constraint");
        if ( condition ){
            rconn.voidEval("constraint");
        }else{
            rconn.assign("constraint");
        }
        if(condition){
            rconn.voidEval("constraint");
        }else{
            rconn.voidEval("constraint");
        }
        rconn.eval("constraint").asStrings();
    }
    for (String[] item : map.values()){
        rconn.assign("constraint",item);
        rconn.voidEval("constraint");
    }
}
```

Comment: Assignments should not take very long time. What if you run your logic in native R? Rserve should not impact the performance that much. And what platform you run Rserve on?

Comment: content is not lost in RCaller, if you use runAndReturnResultOnline() rather than the runAndReturnResult() . See the page http://stdioe.blogspot.com.tr/2011/09/rcaller-support-for-sequential-commands.html for an example and the page http://stdioe.blogspot.com.tr/2014/06/new-documentation-for-rcaller.html for some documents

Comment: But what i want is that rcaller object should hold the result so that it can be accessed from other methods. This is because i may be re-using the previously assigned variables. So if I use RCaller i would have to run and return and then reassign the variable to R . Also most of my code runs in a loop and i would like to have multiple objects  be present in the context of the execution.